# Unable to connect to mysql database residing in an EC2 instance from another EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have 2 EC2 instances in AWS with CentOS 7 OS. I have installed Apache, MySQL and PHP for my project. Now I am trying to connect to the DB residing inside one EC2 instance from another EC2 instance. But it is throwing "Unable to connect" error.I have created a database specific user with all privileges which I am using to connect. Interestingly I am able to connect to the databse from my localhost but not from another EC2. There is no bind-address or skip-network line in my.cnf. Shall I need to add any rule in Security Group? Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give specifics of how you have connected such as remote ssh as localhost. Also what have you done in any configs and security groups

Comment: I am trying to connect using host address which is an Elasitc IP of the instance. Security Rule gave as SSH to access through shell and HTTP as Inbound rule. As Outbound Rule All traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your current security group or groups, and assuming you are not allowing all traffic in/out, the answer is: **Yes. You need to allow traffic between EC2 instances in the security group/s.** 
You can create a rule for the specific traffic/port in and/or out or you can open up everything.

If this is not a production environment I would suggest you allow all traffic in and out for both instances (double check that both instances are part of this security group or that both of their groups allow all traffic in and out), to quickly verify if this is a security group issue or not. Then you'd narrow down and lock this down to the actual connections that your application needs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you pls suggest what should be the rule. Actually I noticed if I give host ip instead of localhost then from the same instance itself I am not able to connect to the db.